# Categorizing a data frame column in R using grep on a list of a list

Tags: r, categories, sublist

I have a column of a data frame that I want to categorize.

```
> df$orgName
[1] "Hank Rubber"             "United Steel of Chicago"
[3] "Muddy Lakes Solar"       "West cable"
```

I want to categorize the column using the `categories` list below that contains a list of subcategories.

```
metallurgy <- c('steel', 'iron', 'mining', 'aluminum', 'metal', 'copper' ,'geolog')
energy <- c('petroleum', 'coal', 'oil', 'power', 'petrol', 'solar', 'nuclear')
plastics <- c('plastic', 'rubber')
wiring <- c('wire', 'cable')

categories = list(metallurgy, energy, plastics, wiring)
```

So far I've been able to use a series of nested ifelse statements to categorize the column as shown below, but the number of categories and subcategories keeps increasing.

```
df$commSector <- 
ifelse(grepl(paste(metallurgy,collapse="|"),df$orgName,ignore.case=TRUE), 'metallurgy',
   ifelse(grepl(paste(energy,collapse="|"),df$orgName,ignore.case=TRUE), 'energy',
          ifelse(grepl(paste(plastics,collapse="|"),df$orgName,ignore.case=TRUE), 'plastics',
                 ifelse(grepl(paste(wiring,collapse="|"),df$orgName,ignore.case=TRUE), 'wiring',''))))
```

I've thought about using a set of nested `lapply` statements, but I'm not too sure how to execute it.

Lastly does anyone know of any R Libraries that may have functions to do this.

Thanks a lot for everyone's time.

Cheers.

Comment: Where is `df` in the example`

Comment: It's a really large data frame, and some of the data is kind of sensitive.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one categories in each element of "orgName"?

Comment: It might be possible for each element of orgName to be classified into more than one category, but it is very rare.  For now I'll just be satisfied having one category for each element of orgName.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to get the `vector`s as a `name`d `list` using `mget`, then `paste` the elements together (as showed by OP), use `grep` to find the index of elements in 'orgName' that matches (or use `value = TRUE`) extract those elements, `stack` it create a `data.frame`.

```
 res <- setNames(stack(lapply(mget(c("metallurgy", "energy", "plastics", "wiring")), 
    function(x) df$orgName[grep(paste(x, collapse="|"), 
                  tolower(df$orgName))])),  c("orgName", "commSector"))
 res
 #                  orgName  commSector
 #1 United Steel of Chicago metallurgy
 #2       Muddy Lakes Solar     energy
 #3             Hank Rubber   plastics
 #4              West cable     wiring
```

If we have other columns in 'df', do a `merge`

```
 merge(df, res, by = "orgName")
 #                  orgName commSector
 #1             Hank Rubber   plastics
 #2       Muddy Lakes Solar     energy
 #3 United Steel of Chicago metallurgy
 #4              West cable     wiring
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(orgName = c("Hank Rubber", "United Steel of Chicago", 
            "Muddy Lakes Solar", "West cable"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help akrun.  I'm still debugging the code, and might not have time to finish debugging until later tonight.